# Why TensorFlow in Go didn't find the optimizer as python?

Tags: go, tensorflow

I am a newbie of `TensorFlow` in `Go`.

There are some doubts during my first traing demo. I just find one optimizer in Go's `wrappers.go`.

But i learn the demos of python,they has serveral optimizers. Like

```
GradientDescentOptimizer
AdagradOptimizer
AdagradDAOptimizer
MomentumOptimizer
AdamOptimizer
FtrlOptimizer
RMSPropOptimizer
```

The similar prefix of func like `ResourceApply...
                                         GradientDescent
                                         Adagrad
                                         AdagradDA
                                         Momentum
                                         Adam
                                         Ftrl
                                         RMSProp`.

And they return a option.I don't know what are their purpose. I cant find the relation of them and optimizer.

And how can i make a train in `Go` by `TensorFlow`.

What should I should use like python's `tf.Variable` in `Go`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** train a Tensorflow model using Go.

The only thing you can do is load a pre-trained model and use it for the inference.

You can't because the Go implementation lacks the `Variable` support, therefore it's impossible to train anything at the moment.

Comment: yes, I also wrote it in my article (I'm galeone, you're mailing me these days): read it carefully!

Comment: Oh what a coincidence!Thanks for your help in these days.Now i've changed another frame to learn neural network.Do you have some useful resource to give me advice ?

Comment: Use tensorflow & python. The tensorflow manual is a good starting place. For a more theoretical approach, just look at some university course on ML and you'll be fine